# How to get featured_media of a post with getEntityRecords?

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to get a specific post featured_media with getEntityRecords. but I couldn't.

```
select("core").getEntityRecords("root", "media", { post: 92 })
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution... must use `getEntityRecord` not `getEntityRecods`:

```
select("core").getEntityRecord("postType", "attachment", post.featured_media);
```